# Variable in array undefined when trying to use it in an array, but is defined when console logging

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to add dropdown items and handle the click based on the string value of the dropdown item. When I do console.log(props.storedSections[x]), it logs the correct value for the string. However when I try to use it to store the string in to check in handleSectionClick, it is just left as undefined and I have tried wrapping it in {}, `{}`, and ${}, but none of it works as I intend it to. Any ideas? Also it is a useState variable that is passed down from a parent component but that shouldn't matter since it displays properly when console logged.

here is the declaration of the sections useState object

```
    const [sections, setSections] = useState([<Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>handleSectionClick("Work")}>Work</Dropdown.Item>])
```

Here is the useEffect function I am using to take the sections variable and add extra items to it using the strings stored in the storedSections useState variable

```
useEffect(() =>{
        //gets the new list without the Add New object
        let newSectionList = [...sections.slice(0, sections.length-1)]
        for(var x = 0; x < props.storedSections.length; x++){
            if(sections.indexOf(props.storedSections[x]) == -1)
            //adds the new object that they want to add
            newSectionList.push(<Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>handleSectionClick(props.storedSections[x])}>{props.storedSections[x]}</Dropdown.Item>)
        }
        
        //then adds in the Add new object again
        newSectionList.push(<Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>handleSectionClick("Add New")}>Add New</Dropdown.Item>)
        
        setSections[newSectionList]
        setNewSectionTest(newSectionList)
    }, [])
```

Here is the code for handleSectionClick. If I console log the values here they are undefined.

```
    function handleSectionClick(item) {
    //if they select the Add New section from the dropdown then bring up the option to type a new one
    if (item === "Add New") {
        setNewSection(true)
      }
      //updates the header for the dropdown and keeps track of which section should be saved for the task
      else{
        setCurrentSection(item)
      }
  }
```

In my App.jsx I declare the storedSections like this

```
const [storedSections, setStoredSections] = useState(['test1', 'test2'])
```

The main goal of what I am trying to do is to take a dropdown menu with preset items in it, give the user the ability to add their own custom options to the dropdown menu and have the new values persist on a rerender. I plan to move this to a more complicated format including a database that stores each users custom dropdowns, but for now I am just confused why the value is stored properly and is console logged properly but when I try to use it in the declaration of the Dropdown Item, it reads as undefined.

Comment: you can try to use let instead of var inside of for loop

Comment: This isn't quite enough code to determine the issue. If possible, please show as much of the component as possible including all state declarations and the handler this code is contained within. What does an example entry inside of the `props.storedSections` look like? What happens to `newSectionList` after this code?

Comment: Please [edit] the post with any new details and code snippets. The comments are just about the worst place for code. Storing JSX in React state is anti-pattern. State should be the data and the component should render the data to JSX. Please also share a more complete [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the post, sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one very obvious problem is var x = 0 in for loop, try changing it to let x = 0; as in below code, and also add dependent props in useEffect dependency array

e.g. useEffect(() => {}, []) here in [] add props.storedSections and sections if it is also coming from props, also handleSectionClick if is hooks returned function

```
useEffect(() =>{
    //gets the new list without the Add New object
    let newSectionList = [...sections.slice(0, sections.length-1)]
    for(let x = 0; x < props.storedSections.length; x++){
        if(sections.indexOf(props.storedSections[x]) == -1)
        //adds the new object that they want to add
        newSectionList.push(<Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>handleSectionClick(props.storedSections[x])}>{props.storedSections[x]}</Dropdown.Item>)
    }
    
    //then adds in the Add new object again
    newSectionList.push(<Dropdown.Item onClick={()=>handleSectionClick("Add New")}>Add New</Dropdown.Item>)
    
    setSections[newSectionList]
    setNewSectionTest(newSectionList)
}, [props.storedSections, sections])
```